# React native touch id not working

Tags: android, ios, react-native, touch-id

I want to create touch id local authentication in react native. I used

npm   `react-native-touch-id`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

var LocalAuth = require('react-native-touch-id')

var YourComponent = React.createClass({
  _pressHandler() {
    LocalAuth.authenticate({
        reason: 'this is a secure area, please authenticate yourself',
        falbackToPasscode: true,    // fallback to passcode on cancel
        suppressEnterPassword: true // disallow Enter Password fallback
      })
      .then(success => {
        AlertIOS.alert('Authenticated Successfully')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        AlertIOS.alert('Authentication Failed', error.message)
      })
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ...
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._pressHandler}>
          <Text>
            Authenticate with Touch ID / Passcode
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
})
```

but it says nothing, i followed this link

https://github.com/ElekenAgency/react-native-touch-id-android

Answer (score 1):

Came here because I've got the same question, but looking at your code I assume you've got lost in mixing libs.

Looking at the line:

```
var LocalAuth = require('react-native-touch-id')
```

You're importing `LocalAuth` which I believe is a part of `react-native-local-auth` library built on top of `react-native-touch-id`, while following a tutorial for 3-rd library which is `react-native-touch-id-android`.

According to their example in the repo, your import should look like this:

```
import Finger from 'react-native-touch-id-android'
```

My guess for the reason it's not crashing on you is because you've installed `react-native-local-auth` somewhere in the process befor trying out `react-native-touch-id-android`.

Better start all over - go to `package.json` and remove the above mentioned libraries, then run `npm install` and then follow the step-by-step guide in the repo you've posted.

I'd be glad if you come back afterwards and report on whether it worked out or not. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use this code it worked for me !

```
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';

TouchID.authenticate('Authentication')
     .then(success => {
              // Success code
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Failure code
            });
```